# Xamarin Android: Ilist<Address> does not contain a definition for 'Any'

Tags: android, xamarin, gps, geolocation, ilist

I'm trying obtain adrress from Location using this steps.
I obtain correctly latitude and longitude, but I need specific address too.
If exist other tutorial to obtain this.

http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/os_device_resources/gps/get_current_device_location/

```
void InitializeLocationManager()
{
    _locationManager = (LocationManager)GetSystemService(LocationService);
    Criteria criteriaForLocationService = new Criteria
                                            {
                                                Accuracy = Accuracy.Fine
                                            };
    IList<string> acceptableLocationProviders = _locationManager.GetProviders(criteriaForLocationService, true);

    if (acceptableLocationProviders.Any())
    {
        _locationProvider = acceptableLocationProviders.First();
    }
    else
    {
        _locationProvider = String.Empty;
    }
}
```

In this code the errors are:

System.Collection.Generic.Ilist does not contain a definition for `'Any'`

Comment: Try it using `if (acceptableLocationProviders.Count>0)`

Comment: and when I need use 'acceptableLocationProviders.First();' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `using System.Linq;` to the top to the source file. [`Any()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is an extension method to `IEnumerable` within the `System.Linq` namespace.